# Is there any free WiFi network available at the HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge Macau Port?

Tags: wifi, macau

Is there any free WiFi network available at the [HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong%E2%80%93Zhuhai%E2%80%93Macau_Bridge) Macau Port?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. According to a [free WiFi service site](http://www.freewifi.mo/en/) created by Macau government, there are 3 locations/areas with WiFi provided. This site (there's an app too) also provide the locations of all free WiFi hotspots that can be used across Macau.

[image: search result]

Somehow the first two result only have Chinese description so let me translate for you.

1. Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge Frontier Post at Macao Port - pick-up and drop-off area in car park within Macau's border
2. Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge Frontier Post at Macao Port - car park pick-up and drop-off area in car park outside Macau's border